# Ajax return notification Function help for grade school student

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

This code was sent to me by a young student. I told his mother that I would seek help in finding him a solution (I am clueless with javascript). it is an ajax return that displays a #notification. He wants to have the page reload if the returned message starts with a certain pattern. Any ALL help is appreciated.

```
  <script>
    function onSuccess(data, status)
    {
        data = $.trim(data);
        $("#notification").html(data);
        $("#notification").fadeIn(1500);
        if(html(data).startsWith("!!!")) {        
            setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload( true ); },1500);
        }
    }

    function onError(data, status)
    {
        // handle an error
    }
```

Comment: Looks fine, if `html` is defined as afunction that returns an object that has a startsWith property that references a function that does what it seems to be doing.

Comment: lol... As clear to me as the code above reads... but, thank you for your time.

Comment: Basically my point is there's nothing syntactically wrong with the code, as long as the `html` method being used exists and returns an expected boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is a string, You can use **[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** to see if the value is `0`; which means the pattern is at the beginning of the string.

```
if(data.indexOf("!!!") == 0)
{
   //yes pattern match
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your time... I just forwarded it to him... probably sleeping... but I will post a follow up tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Does the string have to start with !!! or the html content? There is a difference because <p>   !!!!</p> would technically not start with !!! but it would for the user as they see !!! as the first characters.

Either way you could try this:

```
    if($("#notification").text().indexOf("!!!")===0){        
      setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload( true );},1500);
    ]
```

Comment: Thank You for your time... I just forwarded it to him... probably sleeping... but I will post a follow up tomorrow...